# DPI interface for Raspberry Pi including backlight driver

Tags: raspberry-pi, lcd, interface, backlight

I am designing a DPI interface for my Raspberry Pi ZeroW.

I believe the screen I have is exactly the same as the [Pimoroni Hyperpixel 4.0 Square,](https://shop.pimoroni.com/products/hyperpixel-4-square?variant=30138251444307) just without the chunky interface PCB.

I have the HyperPixel and it works great
My interface will be almost the same as it, but in a different form factor and with some additional circuits incorporated (that are currently on I2C breakouts.)

The main part I am struggling with is driving the LED backlight. This is all the info I currently have on the backlight but am awaiting more from the manufacturer and will update if/when they get me something:

[image: Backlight spec]

1. If I have a separate 12.8V power supply, would the following work to "boost" the PWM output from the Pi to the LEDs?  If not, what is the best approach if I already have the right power lines?

[image: PWM Transistor]

2. What is the best/easiest way to boost the 5V from the Pi to 12.8V so I don't need this external power supply?  I am using EasyEDA and have tried using boost converter chips but the circuits seem overly complex.  On the back of the HyperPixel, what looks like the LED driver circuit is quite efficient in terms of space and component size (red circle below):

[image: Hyperpixel square]

3. Although the actual DPI part is relatively straightforward (following Raspberry Pi's DPI guide, and common sense just matching the pins up), the HyperPixel seems to have a bunch of resistors near the header (blue circle in image above) which roughly seem to align with the RGB pins. Are these just general purpose resistors for protection or something?  Is it recommended to use these for DPI?  Is there a way to calculate their values?

Current circuit:

[image: current circuit]

Comment: Unfortunately nobody is going to stick their necks out without the LED data sheet - what you have is just not sufficient to make a proper recommendation. You can still use a boost circuit (as per you earlier question) but as to putting two strings of LEDs in parallel this again cannot be confirmed because experienced EEs know that parallel LEDs is usually going to end in tears without extra protection circuits.

Comment: Ok thanks I’ll add the data sheet once I hear back from the manufacturer. Any thoughts on the third part?

Comment: I can't answer the third part, sorry.

Comment: Thanks Andy.  Can you tell me exactly what info the data sheet would be missing?  Is it just whether the Backlight is constant current or constant voltage?  Or are there other parameters?  This would help me extract the info from the manufacturer who are currently saying they don't have any more info.

Comment: The fact that you don't have a data sheet made available to you is a big cause for concern. Basically, my rule is don't design anything unless all the components are solidly backed with data sheets and supplied from reputable suppliers. I'm not going to speculate on what the DS may or may not reveal.

Comment: Well I have a data sheet for the LCD, just the backlight section is what I have previously shared and is apparently not enough.  I hadn't expected eight tiny LED's in a 4" screen to be so complicated to simply turn on and off

Comment: Well you can take a guess and assume that a constant current of 40 mA driver will do the job - maybe even the TPS6116 with 2.5 ohms in the FB to ground position might work (as per your previous question) but it's still just a guess.

Comment: OK, thanks, I understand, I'm still pushing the manu for more info and will go from there

Comment: Is there any way I would be able to reverse engineer it or work out the details from the existing screen I have?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of with any degree of confidence - if this is a one-off project I'd assume that a constant current driver of 40 mA would be probably OK.

Comment: Thanks, hopefully I get something from the manu too

Comment: I received confirmation from the manufacturer that the LED’s are constant but no further info yet. Is the TPS 6116 the easiest way to implement a circuit for this?

Comment: Just check that the TPS can deliver a constant current of 40 mA. I think it can because it doesn't sound a lot to deliver but best checking.

Comment: Thanks and regarding the voltage output, would I just use a voltage divider with resistors to limit the max voltage to 12.8V?  Meaning the driver (in this case TPS) would just driver between 0V and 12.8V based on the PWM input.

Comment: This is where the data sheet (or lack of it) is the problem. If I take a guess, I would say that if you pushed a current of 40 mA into the LED, it will develop a forward voltage of typically 12.8 volts. This means that you shouldn't have to worry about doing anything about the voltage because it will settle to a value that is suitable for 40 mA flowing through it. So, choose a resistor like 10 ohm that limits current to 20 mA (as per your last question and my answer) and maybe if that looks OK, try lowering that resistor to 6.8 ohms and see what the voltage across the LED is.

Comment: OK, thanks but I'm confused now.  So with constant current, isn't the voltage adjusted to dim the load up and down?  So if I wire everything with the TPS to provide a 40mA constant current, are you saying that it "should" run at 12.8V when at full power just by itself, then if I dim using the PWM input, it should lower this voltage appropriately? Also, is the TPS the easiest option for this circuit?  There's quite a lot of design parameters. Thanks

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying - it will produce the right voltage to drive 40 mA through the load because it is the 40 mA that is being measured by the Rset resistor and FB requires 200 mV on that pin to start regulating hence 40 mA through 10 ohm = 200 mV. The TPS is actually one of the easier parts but, if in doubt, post a new question with your proposed circuit and someone should be able to double check it.

Comment: Great, thank you so much, I'll post another question once I have worked on the design

Comment: Just to say that the driver circuit worked and the backlight dims perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Did you finish this? Can you share the schematic of your findings?

Comment: @Southstream I have posted what I think was the final circuit as an answer. Hope it helps

Comment: maybe is slightly off topic, but can you point to me to the lcd model ? it will be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From comments

If I take a guess, I would say that if you pushed a current of 40 mA into the LED, it will develop a forward voltage of typically 12.8 volts. This means that you shouldn't have to worry about doing anything about the voltage because it will settle to a value that is suitable for 40 mA flowing through it. So, choose a resistor like 10 ohm that limits current to 20 mA (as per your last question and my answer) and maybe if that looks OK, try lowering that resistor to 6.8 ohms and see what the voltage across the LED is.

> *So with constant current, isn't the voltage adjusted to dim the load
> up and down? So if I wire everything with the TPS to provide a 40mA
> constant current, are you saying that it "should" run at 12.8V when at
> full power just by itself, then if I dim using the PWM input, it
> should lower this voltage appropriately?*

Yes, that's what I'm saying - it will produce the right voltage to drive 40 mA through the load because it is the 40 mA that is being measured by the Rset resistor and FB requires 200 mV on that pin to start regulating hence 40 mA through 10 ohm = 200 mV.

> *Just to say that the driver circuit worked and the backlight dims
> perfectly. Thanks! – Bassline Soup*

Comment: Hmm, I was slightly hasty there.  The backlight works at 100% duty cycle, there are a few flickers on dimming but I'm happy with just on and off tbh for the time being. Thanks!

Comment: Can you show the circuit you used - maybe you need to add a power supply capacitor across the output to ground circa 10 uF?

Comment: Added to question

Comment: Try increasing C9 to 10 uF and see what happens.

Comment: OK, I'll give it a go thanks

Comment: Tried 10 uF for C9 and still flickering at anything below 100% duty cycle

Comment: Turns out that the rpi.gpio library is creating the flickering.  Using pigpio it now works without any flickering. Thanks again!

Comment: Excellent result.

Answer (score 0):

I think this was the final circuit but I can't really remember as it was a while ago. Hope it helps someone.

[image: Solution Schematic]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).